# how to show and hide field in magento admin form on change function

Tags: magento-1.8

i need to hide form field on on change in magento admin.
I need to know that how can i show hide field with his labels in magento admin form
my form

```
$fieldset->addField('style_content', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('magazine')->__('Select available Slider Styles'),
            'name' => 'style_content',           
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'value' => 'Yes',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('magazine')->__('Yes'),
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => 'No',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('magazine')->__('No'),
                ),
            ),
            'onchange'  => 'onchangeStyleShow()',
        ));
```

Answer (score 5):

magento is provide to add JavaScript function on admin form using `setAfterElementHtml`  where you can right your custom script.

```
$field->setAfterElementHtml('<script>
 function onchangeStyleShow(){
// here goes your custom Javascript
}
</script>');
```

Comment: please answer this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45809/how-to-create-code-pool-in-magento

Answer (score 4):

Detail code using `setAfterElementHtml`:

```
// This is the field to hide
$fieldset->addField('field_to_hide', text, array(
    'label'  => $this->__('Test'),
));

// Select field
$styleContentField = $fieldset->addField('style_content', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('magazine')->__('Select available Slider Styles'),
            'name' => 'style_content',           
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'value' => 'Yes',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('magazine')->__('Yes'),
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => 'No',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('magazine')->__('No'),
                ),
            ),
            'onchange'  => 'onchangeStyleShow()',
        ));

// Javascript function to show/hide field_to_hide
$styleContentField->setAfterElementHtml('
                        <script>
                        function onchangeStyleShow() {                                              
                            $("field_to_hide").toggle()
                        }
                        </script>
                    ');
```

**More details:** [Magento: Show/Hide Admin Form fields using Javascript](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-show-hide-admin-form-fields-using-javascript/)